# Finding the exact coordinates of circle's extreme east and west points on a sphere

Tags: intersection, spherical-geometry

I'm currently implementing the Bentley-Ottman algorithm applied to spheres, involving intersections of many spheres on one sphere, circles in most cases of course.
This requires locating "event" points on the sphere (ie: points where something "special" happened, such as extreme points of intersection circles or intersections between these).

My question is very similar to [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19221/find-tangent-point-on-circle-furthest-east-or-west), mainly because I'm asking for the exact same thing : the eastmost and westmost points of a circle on a sphere, in my case named the *start* and *end* points of the circle. These points have the particularity of being the tangency points between the circle and a special longitude.
The problem resides in finding these as **exact** coordinates.

I'm working with the [CGAL](http://cgal.org/) library, which provides a great deal of exact intersection primitives, and these are in my opinion probably the most appropriate way to find the exact start-end points.

So far I've tried to reduce the problem to a simpler one : instead of finding the longitudes of these points, I'm trying to find the height of the horizontal plane which contains these two points.
Using the following notations :

- S : start point
- E : end point
- C : center of the circle (not on the sphere of course)
- r : radius of the circle
- O : center of the sphere
- R : radius of the sphere
- h : height of the horizontal plane containing the start-end points
- H : intersection between the pole axis and the horizontal plane
  containing the start-end points
- phi : the latitude containing C
- phi' : the latitude containing the start-end points.

Starting out from the formula based on the Law of Sines, from the last post :

```
sin(phi') = sin(phi) cos(r/R)
```

We notably have :

```
h = R sin(phi')
sin(phi) = OC / R
```

Giving finally :

```
h = OC cos(r / R)
```

This is as far as I've gotten, and I'm stuck on finding an algebraic form of this cosine.

Comment: You state your question is the same as an existing one. Then you go on to reproduce part of an answer. Finally you ask for "an algebraic form of [a] cosine." Mathematically there is no such thing: to find *h*, you need to compute the inverse cosine (arccosine). If you wish to comment on or follow up on the duplicate, then please do so there.