# How to place markers on the outline of a circle in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, mathematics

I have the center of a circle and it's radius and I need to place variable amount of markers on the outline/stroke of the circle. The distance between this markers should kept same, so if I have 8 markers to put on the orbit, each of them has 45 degree space (360 / 8) and also it should not be hard-coded as the number of markers is variable.

I wanted to know what is the right way for calculating the Geo-coordinates of each marker?

here you can see an example, the outer marker should move on, however I can't calculate the proper LatLng values.

[image]

---

I finally came up with this formula:

```
var dg = 90;
var lat = Math.sin(dg * Math.PI / 180) * r + center_geo_lat;
var lng = Math.cos(dg * Math.PI / 180) * r + center_geo_lng;
```

If you look at snapshots you can see that markers at 0 and 180 degree has placed quite fine, but it seems there is something wrong with other markers. It's gonna works fine for me, because I don't need such a perfect accuracy, however I'm wondering what's cause the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see this Question and Answers for the info on the stretch in a North/South direction http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6822/why-is-the-straight-line-path-across-continent-so-curved

Comment: I merged your questions since the second one was following up on your first attempt at solving the question posed in the first one.

Comment: @Mahdi What is radius' unit in this question ... meters, kms, miles etc ?

Comment: @HarisurRehman Sorry I can't really remember. I guess that should be kilometres -- same as earth's radius unit, in this example, but I might be wrong.

Comment: No its not kilometres, just tested.
https://i.imgur.com/dKdiNp4.png

Comment: @HarisurRehman Try it as meter then. I doubt if it's mile.

Comment: did you ever figure this out, i'm looking to try something similar?

Comment: @LeeSmith Unfortunately I don't think there is any solution for that. The projection of the map is distorted/stretched, so placing a perfect circle -- or any of other shape for that matter, will be displayed distorted as well. We don't notice this distortion on the map itself, because the map itself doesn't have any regular shapes in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is all down to the projection you're using. Looks like your code is correct, but basically you can't assume that by travelling one unit longitudinally on a map will look the same as the same distance latitudinally.

This has a nice explanation of the differences in projections (see the bit under Tissot's indicatrix):

http://geokov.com/education/map-projection.aspx

Comment: hey, thanks! I'm reading that now, but is there any simple solution for that or not?

Comment: You might also need to consider whether the circles you have plotted are showing you what you really want - or whether these should be ellipses.

Comment: Simple solution is to choose a projection which preserves the shape of areas on the map, i.e. one that is conformal.

Comment: I need circles, i guess ...

Comment: Meters also didn't work correctly