# Whats the unit of circle's radius in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, spherical-geometry

I need to know what is the unit of radius (e.g. miles, kilometers etc) in following question:
[How to place markers on the outline of a circle in google maps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/37615/109969)

Comment: CRS is probably [web Mercator](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7483/), but I'm not sure... If so, unit is meter.

Comment: Yes, Web Mercator, but meters in Web Mercator should not be trusted for distance.