# What is a delta in lat/lon called?

Tags: spherical-geometry

What is the delta between two lat/lon pairs called? Delta degrees? Arcs?

Is it some quantity of distance but what is its unit of measurement?

And related: Can we use pythagoras to calculate this distance?

eg. `d = (0, 3) and (4, 0) = 5?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the simple Pythagorean theorem as that one's for planes whereas the distances you are talking about now are on a curve. For that, you'll have to use spherical trigonometry. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance):

> Let [image]  be the geographical latitude
>   and longitude of two points (a base "standpoint" and the destination
>   "forepoint"), respectively, and [image] 
>   their absolute differences; then [image],
>   the central angle between them, is given by the spherical law of
>   cosines:
>
> [image]
>
> The distance d, i.e. the arc length, for a sphere of radius r and
>   [image]  given in radians, is then
>
> [image]
>
> Note that using r = 6,371.009 metres is appropriate for calculating
>   great-circle distances between points on the Earth's surface, in which
>   case the result d will also be in metres.

It's called a [great circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) btw.

Comment: Ah, and an arc would be the difference between two points on the same line of lat or lon?

Comment: (1) The Wikipedia formula is usually not used in practice, due to numerical problems in computing the inverse cosine of small angles: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4906. (2) "Arc" is a vague term. In the context of this question, Ricky, you probably mean "geodesic." However, "lines" of latitude are not geodesics (except the Equator itself): that is to say, in traversing from point A to point B (both on a common latitude), you do *not* stay at a constant latitude.  See [Why is the 'straight line' path across a continent so curved?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6822).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a [Euler Pole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_pole) plus an angular displacement used to describe "delta".  This is used a lot in [plate reconstruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plate_reconstruction#Euler_poles), where these deltas are often referred to as "rotations", but I'm not sure if that is a formal definition.

[image]